# Polymorphic relation on eloquent event

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 2 classes, `Coordinate` and `Hunt`

```
class Coordinate extends Model {

    public function locatable(){
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

and

```
class Hunt extends Model {
    public function coordinate() {
        return $this->morphOne('App\Coordinate', 'locatable');
    }
}
```

Then I create a new instance of the models using

```
$cord = new Coordinate;
$hunt = new Hunt;

$hunt->save();
$hunt->coordinate->save($cord);
```

Now I listen to the saved event of the `Hunt`

```
class HuntSaved {
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $hunt;

    public function __construct(Hunt $hunt) {
        dd($hunt->coordinate);
        $this->hunt = $hunt;
    }


}
```

The strange thing is that the `dd` here returns `null`.
I cannot save the `Coordinate` first due too its `locatable_type` and `locatable_id` which are `not null` in the database.

My question is, how can I handle the saved event using native eloquent events and get the related model.

Comment: `$hunt->coordinate()->save($cord)`

Answer (score 0):

In your relationship, you should create coordinate first and then create hunt.

```
$coordinate->hunt()->create(array());
```

Comment: Call to a member function save() on null

Comment: important part is `coordinate()`. If it returns null, there is a problem in the relationship.

Comment: Sorry I indeed missed the `()`, with them included I get another error though namely: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'locatable_id' cannot be null

Comment: when calling `$hunt->save();`, check the database to see any new record inserted or not? This error means hunt don't have `id`!

Comment: Don't you need to save the $cord first? Otherwise there's no $cord->id to save into locatable_id of $hunt

Comment: @Matey the locatable_id field is in the coordinates table which means the hunt needs to be saved first, but when saving this first the saved event will be called before the coordinate is saved and thus it is null

Comment: That with the correct data still gives the missing locatable_id error

Comment: AFAIK you cannot use a create method on a polymorphic relation (since you cannot define the class which needs to be created)

Comment: That'll insert an locatable_id of 0 and and locatable_type of ""